# Event keeps null value

Tags: c#, exception, events, null

I am trying to fire event from one control to another, but it keeps null value. I have declared a delegate and event, and created method that checks if event is not null on 2nd control. That method is called on button click and supposed to notify 1st control to do some action (refreshing grid data)

```
//Child form
public partial class InventuraForm
{
    SqlClient client = null;   

    public delegate void NekiDelegat();
    public event NekiDelegat MojEvent;  


    public void SendEvent()
    {
        if (MojEvent != null) MojEvent(); //MojEvent keeps showing null 
    }

    //Saving data and exiting the control
    public void tsbSpremiZatvori_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //some code

        SendEvent();
    }
}           


//Parent form
public partial class InventuraFormPregled 
{ 
    InventuraForm _inv = null;

  public InventuraFormPregled()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _inv = new InventuraForm();
        _inv.MojEvent += new InventuraForm.NekiDelegat(LoadGridData);          

    }     

 //refresing the data on grid
 private void LoadGridData()
 {
 //some code
 }

}
```

I appretiate any help, thx.

Answer (score 0):

open the childform by _inv .Show() method.

Comment: I am trying to fire this event while CLOSING the child form.

Comment: have you  used the object of your childform(_inv) for showing the method (i.e _inv.Show()).

Comment: @user3343010 There already is a closing event.  You don't need to create one yourself.